# I am sending data to google sheets api using golang, when headers get updated, sheets api is overwriting the existing headers instead of appending new

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, linkedhashmap

I am sending data to google sheets api using golang, when headers get updated, sheets api is overwriting the existing headers instead of appending new headers.

Screenshot when everything works fine:
[Working Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePLos.png)

Screenshot when headers are updated:
[Sheet screenshot when headers updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EKU8.png)

The expected behaviour in second screenshot would be it should created another column as 'surname' and then append data to that column.

The corresponding golang code for this same:

```
func SendDataToSheet(formResponse *models.FormResponse, integration models.Integration) error {
    var sheetIntegration models.SheetIntegration
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(integration.Integration), &sheetIntegration); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    decToken, err := utils.Decrypt(integration.Token)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tokenSource := oauth2.Token{}
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(decToken), &tokenSource)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    if !tokenSource.Valid() {
        config := utils.ConfigGoogleSheets()
        tokenConfig := config.TokenSource(ctx, &tokenSource)
        newTokenSource, _ := tokenConfig.Token()

        encToken, err := json.Marshal(newTokenSource)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        encTokenString, err := utils.Encrypt(string(encToken))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        integration.Token = encTokenString
        tokenSource = *newTokenSource

        if err := initializers.DB.Save(&integration).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    sheetsService, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&tokenSource)))
    if err != nil {
        integration.Error = err.Error()
        integration.Connected = utils.Bool(false)
        if err := initializers.DB.Save(&integration).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    dataMap := linkedhashmap.New()
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(formResponse.Response), &dataMap); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    headersRangeData := "!A1:Z1"
    valuesRangeData := "!A2:Z2"

    headers := []interface{}{}
    values := []interface{}{}

    for _, key := range dataMap.Keys() {
        if key != "redirect" && key != "password" {
            headers = append(headers, key)
            val, _ := dataMap.Get(key)
            values = append(values, val)
        }
    }

    valueRange := &sheets.ValueRange{
        Values: [][]interface{}{values},
    }

    headersRange := &sheets.ValueRange{
        Values: [][]interface{}{headers},
    }

    _, err = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(sheetIntegration.SheetId, headersRangeData, headersRange).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        integration.Error = err.Error()
        integration.Connected = utils.Bool(false)
        if err := initializers.DB.Save(&integration).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    _, err = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(sheetIntegration.SheetId, valuesRangeData, valueRange).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        integration.Error = err.Error()
        integration.Connected = utils.Bool(false)
        if err := initializers.DB.Save(&integration).Error; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Initially data was not being inserted in actual order because map was used, so I have used linkedhashmap which helped to order the elements but still its failing when headers are updated.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.